# Designing a dynamic responsive week calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a dynamic responsive week calendar, using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Here's my current implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/dvirazulay/Lhe7C/ (was a little long to paste in here in full)

And here is a current screenshot of it:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is a design which will be fully dynamic - generating the initial view from my back-end is no issue, but is a little complicated, as my current implementation uses **tables**. I fear it will be hard to maintain it on the JavaScript side of things, i.e removing events/adding them on the fly.

Obviously, I picked tables as it made sense to me - a week calendar is basically a table. I'll describe my design:

1. An event may span for more than 30 minutes, so I use `rowspan` to define how many hours it should span on.
2. There might be two events conflicting (I don't allow more than two). As it currently set-up, they show up next to each other, each taking 50% of the event width and taking as much as height as they need to represent the ending time.
3. On the back-end side, I calculate how many `td` I need to skip in order not to have extra columns at the end of the table (as `rowspan` pushes some to the right)

**My questions are the following:**

- Is this the right approach?
- Should I apply the same back-end logic to the front-end, and re-calculate the amount of `tr`/`td` to show according to the amount of events I have, or is there a better solution for this?

Ideally, a good answer should describe how to handle events on the front-end side without complications or an alternate (responsive!) design for this issue.

I don't want to use an existing plugin, as I've searched and tried multiple ones, and I want to keep this really light weight, but if you have a great suggestion for one that fulfills the requirements - I would love to check it out! (jQuery week calendar is too slow and cluttered for example)

**Note**: I have no intention to support browsers older than IE9.

Comment: Any way you can open source this on GitHub. I would love to contribute

Comment: @jonperl, I ended up keeping my back-end & AJAX refreshing solution, but I'm still not comfortable with it (or the source code of it). As soon as I have some free time I'll try to generalize it and port it to JavaScript and deploy it to GitHub. Will let you know, thanks for the interest!

Comment: insted of desining it from scrach why cant you try full calendar

Comment: Did you ever end up releasing the full source to this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching the issues and consulting with a few front-end experts, I've concluded that keeping it as tables is the best option, even if generating it is not trivial.

While this decision makes it hard to dynamically change the schedule without re-generating the whole table, the benefits of styling elements that *should* be a table as a table pay up - aligning, widths, heights, borders, etc. are all easy to control and work great cross-browser.

An important note is that this approach is making the responsiveness of the schedule a trivial quality.

Comment: Just wondering, would `display: table` have given you best of both? Why not?

Comment: @AdamLynch, sorry for the late response (I actually read it long ago and noted to myself I should respond), but I don't see much benefit of CSS tables compared to HTML ones. For me, it is much clearer to read a source of a table when the tag names are descriptive, instead of searching for the class property or the CSS file. 
I would love to hear though of how `display: table` and its friends can solve this better than tables :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm no expert on this, I've struggled with tables vs. CSS for a reponsive calendar before. I was asking more out of curiosity than anything :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a table is a good approach.

Ok, this is a jQuery based solution to the "rowspans are pushed right" problem.
The origin of the problem is a wrong table generation in the backend.

For example if a td with rowspan="3" is rendered, then the td's at the same column index position in the next two rows will be affected and pushed to the right. This is undesired.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>07:30</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Event 07:30 to 09:00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>08:00</td>
    <td>Should not be rendered.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>08:30</td>
    <td>Should not be rendered.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>09:00</td>
    <td>C</td>
</tr>
```

The correct solution is a correct table generation in the backend.
Rendering td's after the rowspan should simply not happen.
If you know, that you are rendering a rowspan="3", then act accordingly. :)

Anyway, if it's not possible to modify the table rendering, then use jQuery to fix it:

http://jsfiddle.net/9tQvu/3/

Answer (score 1):

**[dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) - Ajax/JavaScript Event Calendar**

dhtmlxScheduler is a JavaScript event calendar that allows you to add a Google-like scheduler to your web app or website. Intuitive drag-and-drop interface allows the end users to quickly manage events and appointments in different views: Day, Week, Month, Year, Agenda, Timeline, etc. Very lightweight (about 20Kb gzipped), highly customizable, and fast, dhtmlxScheduler provides a quick way to add an Ajax-based event calendar on a web page.

Comment: [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) is not responsive and doesn't give a very precise indication of an event's duration.

Comment: @dvir-azulay is not asking for product suggestions but what the best development method is for handling event schedules.

Either way, the *Touch* module for [dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it.

If I were you I would probably use divs though because they are more manageable and easier to use CSS on and are more standard.

Other than that I think you're taking a good approach and you should probably do the front end the same way as the back end because you know it works.

As far as handling events I would just sort divs by type using classes and then use event handlers with the types of events you want to use (I don't know what you'd want besides click though) on those corresponding classes.

Comment: It's actually really hard to maintain with a table. I have to fetch all the events from it and re-calculate the amount of TD/TR I have to use, and then build it. It doesn't feel right to me...

Could you describe how to design it properly with DIVs? I find it hard to think of DIVs for a tabular data problem

Comment: I can use the table and position elements over it with JavaScript, but that kills my responsiveness - unless I update it on resize. Is that any sort of a standard? Tables are perfect for me if there's a better way to handle them with JS

Answer (score 0):

what happens when an event is overlapping only partially with another, i mean, 2 overlapping events takes 50% of the witdh, but if one of them will finish sooner and the other later, the one that continue, does it takes all the width of the "next" row or continue at 50% of the width? what happen if the event A is from 8:00 to 8:30 and event B is from 8:00 to 18:00 ? it should be nice that the event B will fullup the width until there is another overlapping event..but i guess it could be a little tricky.
just a thought. Happy coding, this is really a nice project.

Comment: I think it'd look a little odd, like Tetris, if they only overlapped (say, 50%-width each) for the time that events overlap. I quite like how @dvir-azulay has handled this on `Monday from 1200-1330`.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS and divs, instead of table cells, could be more precise and will certainly be easier to calculate client-side and retain responsiveness. Here's a pseduo-CSS/JS example for the first event:

```
.event:first-child {
    height: `(1.5/24)*100`%; /* 6.25%, based on duration */
    position: absolute;
    top: `(10/24)*100`%; /* 41.7%, based on event start */
}
```